# stop vimeo video on loop of modals

Tags: jquery, laravel, iframe, bootstrap-modal, vimeo

I'm working on a portfolio website and I want stop a vimeo or youtube video when the modal close, and I can do that. the problem is in the next project modals, every iframe of all modals have the same SRC. the same video

This is my code

```
@foreach ($rs as $r)
<div class="col-md-6 portfolio-item">
       <div class="portfolio">
           <a class="portfolio-link" href="#{{$r->id}}" data-toggle="modal">
             <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/vimeo_thumbnails/{{$r->thumbnail}}" alt="" width="1280" height="720">
           </a>
             <a class="portfolio-link" href="#{{$r->id}}" data-toggle="modal">
               <div class="portfolio-head">
                 <h3 class="portfolio-text">{{$r->title}} ({{$r->year}})</h3>
                 <h4>{{$r->author}}</h4>
              </div>
             </a>
           </div>
     </div>
<!-- modal -->

     <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="{{$r->id}}" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
         <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
           <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-remodal-action="close" onclick="stopVideo()">
               <div class="lr">
                   <div class="rl">
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-12">
                   <div class="modal-body">
                   <h3 class="text-center"><strong>{{$r->title}}</strong></h3>
                   <h4 class="text-center">({{$r->year}})</h4>
                 </br>
                   <center>
                     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">

                         <div class='embed-container'>
                         <iframe class="iframe" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{{$r->link}}?api=1?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                         </div>

                     </div>
                   </center>
                  </br>
                     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                     </br>
                     </br>
                       {!! $r->description !!}
                     </br>
                     </br>
                     </br>
                     <center>
                     <button class="top" id="top"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></button>
                     </center>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   @endforeach
```

Now this is my jquery try's

```
var vidUrl = $("iframe#vimeo").attr('src');


  //Basically stops and starts the video on modal open/close
  $('.portfolio-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $("iframe#vimeo").attr('src','');
  });

  $('.portfolio-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("iframe#vimeo").attr('src', vidUrl);
  });
```

this is the one that works but the iframe SRC's remain the same for all modals

now with vimeo API

```
   var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
   var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

   $('.portfolio-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    player.pause();
  });

   $('.portfolio-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    player.play();
  });
```

(I have included the player.js file on my master blade)
For some reason its not working too and I have this error on my console "topVideo is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick".

Cant find a solution for this problem, can anyone help-me? I even trying fragoloop script and doesnt work too. :/
Thank you all

Comment: It would be better to have only one modal & change the src dynamically

Comment: it should be better for sure but my friend wants a modal for each project :/

Comment: you can load the project details using ajax call

Comment: its impossible to do  it this way? thats a good suggestion! it should be a good challenge ;)

Comment: why impossible it will be easy, you will have id from that you can get the project details then just call the api load the data into modal that set...

Comment: Yes I know, I mean impossible the way Ive done..

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar.  I can't get the last video to stop triggering the ended event listener, but the answer to your question is to add an event listener to the modal.
Check out this pen:  https://codepen.io/mginter/pen/VNVryR?editors=1111

```
// Open/Close overlay
function toggleOverlay(state) { overlay.classList.toggle('video-on'); }
function closeOverlay(e) {
  overlay.classList.toggle('video-on');
  newPlayer.pause().then(function() {newPlayer.unload();}).catch(function(error) { 
  console.log(error); });
}
overlay.addEventListener('click', closeOverlay, false);
```